# Count the no of id if it is not present in another table based on condition using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, exists

I have a table which consists of RepId and its date.

```
Table: 1
RepID   Date
108981  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108981  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-10 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108983  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108983  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
```

I have another table Which consists of RepId and their logTime.

```
Table: 2
repID   logTime
108981  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108981  2013-04-09 00:00:00.000
108982  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108983  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108983  2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
108984      2013-04-10 00:00:00.000
```

I want the count of RepId from table 1, when the logtime does not exist for that rep from Table 2.

In this case I need the output as

```
repId       RepCount
108982      1
```

as the date '2013-04-10 00:00:00.000' does not exists in table 2 for the RepId - 108982.

I have used the query as

```
select
    t1.RepID, count(t1.RepID) as 'Rep Count'
from
    table1 t1
where
    not exists
    (select t2.repID from table2 t2 where
     CONVERT(date, t2.logTime) between '2013-04-08 00:00:00.000' and '2013-04-11 00:00:00.000')
group by
    t1.RepID
```

but it always returns nothing. Please help to get out of this problem....

Comment: No primary keys? Both those tables have duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN here.

```
SELECT 
  t1.repID, COUNT(t1.repID)  
FROM
  table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table2 t2
ON
  t1.repID = t2.repID
AND
  t1.Date = t2.logTime
WHERE
  t2.repID IS NULL
GROUP BY
  t1.repID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to express this as `not in`:

```
select t1.RepID, count(t1.RepID) as 'Rep Count'
from table1 t1
where t1.repid not in (select t2.repID
                       from table2 t2
                       where CONVERT(date, t2.logTime) between '2013-04-08 00:00:00.000' and '2013-04-11 00:00:00.000'
                       )
group by t1.RepID
```

Or use a correlated subquery or a `left outer join`.

The problem with your query is that you are looking for the existence (or lack thereof) of *any* record during that period, and one must exist.  You really want to look for a record for the given repId.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not relating the subquery in not exists to the outer query, so the not exists clause always returns false. Try something like this:

```
select
    t1.RepID, count(t1.RepID) as 'Rep Count'
from
    table1 t1
where
    not exists
    (select t2.repID from table2 t2 where t2.repId = t1.repId and
     CONVERT(date, t2.logTime) between '2013-04-08 00:00:00.000' and '2013-04-11 00:00:00.000')
group by
    t1.RepID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    t1.RepID, count(t1.RepID) as 'Rep Count'
from
    table1 t1
where
    not exists
    (select * from table2 t2 where
     t2.RepID = t1.RepID and t2.LogTime = t1.Date)
group by
    t1.RepID
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4916d/2)**

Answer (score 0):

**between** will cover given start and end date as well in `table2 logtime` 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 will fall under between condition that's why you are not getting any records

And you should have used `r.RepId not in`

see this demo,  **SQLFiddle DEMO**

either you use **> and <**

```
select
    t1.RepID, count(t1.RepID) as 'Rep Count'
from
    table1 t1
where t1.RepID
    not in
    (select t2.repID from table2 t2 where
     t2.logTime > '2013-04-08 00:00:00.000' and t2.logTime < '2013-04-11 00:00:00.000')
group by
    t1.RepID
```

or your result is correct
change your table2 value

```
108982, '2013-04-11 01:00:00.000'


select
    t1.RepID, count(t1.RepID) as 'Rep Count'
from
    table1 t1
where t1.RepID
    not in
    (select t2.repID from table2 t2 where
     t2.logTime between '2013-04-08 00:00:00.000' and '2013-04-11 00:00:00.000')
group by
    t1.RepID
```